# Why does my app receive KEYCODE_UNKNOWN when a media key is pressed in the Google TV Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

My app is Honeycomb optimized and I've overwritten onKeyDown in my Activity to receive events for the media keys. So far only KEYCODE_UNKNOWN (0) is returned when I press any of the media key in the bottom screen of the emulator. Btw, I use the Google TV addon in it's latest version (revision 2).
Is this an emulator bug or am I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator.html#TVKeys

The keys on the bezel will be supported by Android SDK r14.